# how break terminal after oppening an app on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

So let's say we open an app on ubuntu with terminal. e.x.

```
user$gnome-photos
```

there will be displayed some text with different information about the app events and etc.(i think)and since this is displayed, you cannot run another command , until you terminate the app.
Is there any way to bypass this and be free to type anything other while the app you launched before , is still runninb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Run `gnome-photos &` in the command line to spawn it in a child process or `(gnome-photos &)` to spawn it in a new process.

Comment: thx.Also I think it would be better to run the command with nohup, like : user$ nohup gnome-photos &

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put an `&` at the end to put the app in the background:

As in:

> user$ gnome-photos &

Once that's done you can "disown" the job.

> user$ disown %1

`%1` is the *job specification*, you type it as is.